# Different results for wilcox.test when using data.frame or vectors as input

Tags: r

So I've run into an odd discrepancy, depending upon how I analyze the same data with the wilcox.test() function in R. In this example, I'm comparing the values in two groups. I can either give them to the wilcox.test function as two separate vectors, or I can give the function a data.frame and use a formula to specify the comparison I want to make. The weird thing is, I end up getting a different value for the test statistic (W), depending upon which input method I use. I've included an example below (R v3.3.1):

```
#Prepare test data
wt_exp = c(0.59, 0.56, 0.45, 0.59, 0.54, 0.13, 0.25, 0.10, 0.15)
kd_exp = c(0.27, 0.27, 0.33, 0.25, 0.22, 0.2, 0.16, 0.2, 0.36, 0.58, 0.51)
test.data_frame = 
    data.frame(Expression = c(wt_exp, kd_exp),
               Genotype = rep(c("WT", "KD"),
                              times=c(length(wt_exp), length(kd_exp))))

#Wilcox test using two input vectors
wilcox.test(wt_exp, kd_exp)

# Result:
# Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction
# 
# data:  wt_exp and kd_exp
# W = 55.5, p-value = 0.6756
# alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
# 
# Warning message:
#     In wilcox.test.default(wt_exp, kd_exp) :
#     cannot compute exact p-value with ties

#Wilcox test using data.frame and formula
wilcox.test(Expression ~ Genotype, data=test.data_frame)

# Result:
# Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction
# 
# data:  Expression by Genotype
# W = 43.5, p-value = 0.6756
# alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
# 
# Warning message:
#     In wilcox.test.default(x = c(0.27, 0.27, 0.33, 0.25, 0.22, 0.2,  :
#                                      cannot compute exact p-value with ties
```

While I realize the p-values are the same in this instance, I'm going to be performing tests like this thousands of times, and I want to be sure of the cause for this so I don't need to keep spot-checking the results. Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have two samples `x` and `y`, the test statistics for this test is essentially the sum of the ranks of the values of `x`. Thus it makes a difference which set of observations is `x` and which are `y` for the test statistic. Compare

```
wilcox.test(wt_exp, kd_exp)
wilcox.test(kd_exp, wt_exp)
```

And note that the value you get from the latter corresponds to the value you get when using the formula syntax.

Note that these all get the same p-values because the statistic is normalized by sample size before the p-value is generated.

Comment: Darn, I thought I'd checked the argument order. Thanks for clearing that up.